# Proper way of handling exceptions in a performance-critical application

Tags: c#, exception

I'm working on an application that processes sequential data in parallel. Datapoints from multiple entities can be processed in parallel, but no two datapoints for the same entity can be processed same time. Second datapoint of the entity A is highly dependent on the outcome of processing of the first datapoint.
But I wonder, what would be the best/right way of handling exceptions that are thrown when processing first datapoint?
I can retry the operation, obviously setting retry count. But what if the operation is unable to complete within the preset number of retries?
Should I crash the app and implement some kind of notification?

Comment: "when processing first datapoint" what type of exceptions are likely to be thrown? Perhaps it is possible to trap the errors.

Comment: So far its only database related. SqlExceptions caused by DB maintenance. But the process cannot yeld for maintenance. And maintenance may last 3-4 hours

Comment: You're asking an application-specific question.  Whether you "crash" the app or not, it's up to you.  Both scenarios are "valid"--but only one is right for you.  Does crashing cause data loss?  Does continuing cause data loss?  etc.  these are questions *you* have to come up with answers for an make a educated decision on what to do (or defer to your users).

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought. Well, continuing would definitely corrupt data. Crashing would be safer bet, but was not sure if it was an acceptable solution

Comment: If continuing corrupts data then not telling the user isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. Catch the exception and continue. Problem: this will corrupt data.
2. Shut down the program as gracefully as you can. Of course, output some message saying why you did that.
3. Set a flag somehow to say, "don't process any more datapoints for this entity," and continue processing other entities. Again, you'd want to notify the user of the error.